# DHCP server & MAC address

Tags: dhcp, ip, database

I have database, where are **MAC addresses** stored and base on that database I assigned the **static IP address** to them. Is there a way to automatically assign the IP address to users, who don't have MAC in my **database** ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [isc-dhcp-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dhcp.html) to do all of your IP address allocations. It can assign a specific IP address based on MAC, while at the same time assigning IP addresses from a separate reserved pool when the MAC address is not one that it knows about.